# Creating a button from an event for android

Tags: java, android, html, button

I have looked for ways to make a button/layoutchange that appears depending on the choice made by the user. It is a dice simulator so if you pick you need a 4 sided die or 6 sided die a different look will pop out. I am looking to get some directions. Should I premake them in html or java? Or should I use another approach? The decision of how many sides gets asked through an alertdialog. Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change layout dynamically you can use generic View to hold the space and inflate appropriate layout into them.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html

Answer (score 0):

You can place the button, that should appear in your XML-layout-file and set its visibility attribute to gone. Like so:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button_1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button"
    android:visibility="gone"
     />
```

Then you could change the visibility programmatically (for example in the OnTouchListener of another button or so).

```
    //retrieve the button created in the xml-layout by its id
    mButton= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_1);

    //change its visibility 
    mButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    mButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

I hope, I could help you.

Best regards,
G_J